# Migrate data from old MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, ruby-on-rails, stored-procedures, backup

I recently rewrote a Java EE web application (running on a MySQL database) to Rails 3.1. The problem now is that the database model of the new application is not the same as the old one because I **added, removed and renamed some attributes**. The database table names are also different.

Is there a way of migrating this data? The only way I can imagine to do this is writing a stored procedure with many ALTER TABLE and CREATE TABLE statements to update the database to the new model.

Thanks in advanced.

**Solution**:

I finally used INSERT..SELECT statements in a mysql stored procedure to migrate the data. INSERT INTO new_schema.new_table SELECT FROM old_schema.old_table. I am now considering making a Rake task to call that procedure and doing other stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to write a script that take the data from the old db and insert thme in the new db. Or you can in some way to connect to the two databases and then make some select and insert query, something like

```
 insert into new_db.table as select old_db.table.field1, ....
```

or

```
 insert into new_db.table (field_1, field_2) values (select old_db.table.field_1, ...)
```

In any way, is a manual process, also if can be automated to some extend with a script

Comment: I my opinion, just sql. Eventually just write down the sql if you need to do it on more than one server

Comment: Thank you very much, I edited my question with the final solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a Store procedure you can try with rails and some sql within the rails console using the information_schema of mysql

```
sql = ActiveRecord::Base.connection()
old_tables = sql.execute "select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema = your_old_schema"
res.each do | old_table|
  old_fields = sql.execute "select distinct column_name, data_type from information_schema.columns where table_name='#{old_table}' and table_schema='your_old_schema'"
  new_fields = sql.execute "select distinct column_name, data_type from information_schema.columns where table_name='#{old_table}' and table_schema='your_new_schema'"
  #compare fields and so on...
end
```